CORS policy issue: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
I'm facing a CORS policy issue in my Laravel application when trying to make a request to an API endpoint from my frontend. The error message I'm receiving is:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://personaltrainerkmm.com/api/admin/login' from origin 'https://fitnesspt.personaltrainerkmm.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.
Here's the relevant part of my Laravel middleware code (OwnCors):

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OwnCors
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization'
        ];
        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            return response('OK')
                ->withHeaders($headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }
}

it seems like the issue arises from the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header containing multiple values ('*, '). However, I'm setting it to a single value of '' in my middleware. I'm unsure why this is happening and how to resolve it.
Could someone please provide insights into why this error might be occurring and how I can fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Does this answer your question? CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' does not match '*, *'
